# Scriptable args in docker-compose file

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose

In my docker-compose file (`docker-compose.yaml`), I would like to set an argument based on a small shell script like this:

```
services:
  backend:
    [...]
    build:
      [...]
      args:
        PKG_NAME: $(dpkg -l <my_package>)
```

In the `Dockerfile`, I read this argument like this:

```
ARG PKG_NAME
```

First of all: I know that this approach is OS-dependent (requires `dpkg`), but for starters I would be happy to make it run on Debian. Also, it's fine it the value is an empty string.

However, `docker-compose up` throws this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "build" option in service "backend": "$(dpkg -l <my_package>)"
```

Is there a way to dynamically specify an argument in the docker-compose file through a shell script (or another way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use variable substitution as described in [compose file documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution)

You are trying to inject a shell construct and this is not supported.

The documentation has [several examples on how to pass vars to compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/). In your case, you could:

1. export the var in your environment:

```
export MY_PACKAGE=$(dpkg -l <my_package>)
```

2. use that var in your compose file with default:

```
      args:
        PKG_NAME: "${MY_PACKAGE:-some_default_pkg}"
```

Comment: Even though your answer is technically "no", thanks for confirmation. Having to add another manual step before starting up docker-compose is unfortunate, but apparently inevitable in this case.